# Clonezilla-SE with another DHCP Server in LAN

Tags: linux, dhcp, clonezilla, pxe-boot, drbl

I want to install Clonezilla-Server(192.168.1.100) in a network that already have a DHCP Server (dd-wrt with dnsmasq - 192.168.1.1).
I've installed Clonezilla-SE on ubuntu Server 10.10, once installed and configured Clonezilla Server i've removed the DHCP-Server and set pxe server address in dnsmasq configuration on DHCP Server :

```
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,,192.168.1.100
```

When i try to start from PXE a Computer in the network clonezilla start, but give me an error that the ipddress of the machine is not given by the clonezilla server and can't continue ...
Someone has already tried to configure Clonezilla-SE in a similar enviroment?

Is there some configuration on DRBL server of Clonezilla that i need to do ?

Answer (score 2):

To make the netboot image accept any dhcp, run this command on the DRBL server: /opt/drbl/sbin/mknic-nbi -c n

The caveat is that DRBL clients may fall back to assuming that the NFS shares are on the **gateway** address given out by DHCP. In a nutshell, DRBL *assumes* that your netmask is 255.255.255.0 and falls back otherwise. You can change this assumption by editing the client **init** script directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'name' of your DHCP server to what clonezilla expects.  I believe this defaults to 'drbl'.  There may be a way to change what name it expects, but I've found the clonezilla documentation somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Use your regular DHCP and replace the DHCP server included with DRBL (isc-dhcp-server) with dnsmasq (includes proxyDHCP mode).

dnsmasq can be configured as **proxyDHCP**. A proxyDHCP only provides the PXE related DHCP info to booting PXE clients (NBP and the IP of the TFTP server hosting it) while the regular (non-pxe) DHCP server will provide IP addresses and related info as usual.
This way you can make both, the service provided by your already in place DHCP, and your PXE server, coexist together w/o interfering each other