# DRBL without modifying the DHCP: Possible?

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, clonezilla, drbl

Following up this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/221265/clonezilla-se-with-another-dhcp-server-in-lan) I'd like to ask:

I use the company's network, but I have no access to the DHCP.
I'd like to set up a DRBL server to be able to (re-)install
a Linux image any time I want to.

As far as I understand, the client starts in PXE and asks the DHCP
server where to find the DRBL server.

Can I still use the PXE+DRBL if I cannot modify the DHCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but you have to replace the DHCP server included with DRBL (isc-dhcp-server) with dnsmasq.

Next dnsmasq should be configured as proxyDHCP. A proxyDHCP only provides the PXE related DHCP info to booting PXE clients (NBP and the IP of the TFTP hosting it) while the regular (untouchable) DHCP server will provide IP addresses and related info as usual.